# Reactjs - Passing Color as Prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm trying to use a color as a prop in a reactjs setting.  In the General_heading component, I want to be able to pass a prop to define the color of the heading, but I can't get it to respond currently.  Thoughts?
in app.js:

```
<div><General_header theme_color="red"/></div>
```

in General_header.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class General_header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {logo_img: props.logo_img,
                  theme_color: props.theme_color};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={[styles.header,{backgroundColor:this.state.theme_color}]}>test
        <img src={this.state.logo_img} alt={'logo'} style={styles.logo_img} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

var styles = {
  header: {
    height: '100px',
    display: 'block'},
  logo_img: {
    height: '40px',
    display: 'inline-block'}

}

export default General_header;
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that whenever props are updated (without the component being unmounted then remounted) your state won't update. I'd suggest checking out the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method, or if you are using 16.3+ then `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

Comment: Also if I'm not mistaken the `style` prop on default components _has_ to be either `null`/`undefined` or an object.

Answer (score 1):

Use camelCase

Have a look at this https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react#naming

```
<GeneralHeader themeColor="red"/>


constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      logoImg: props.logoImg,
     themeColor: props.themeColor
   };
}

<div style={{backgroundColor: this.state.themeColor}}>
```

Comment: Very much a needed fix, but still not running properly.  It looks like this line is breaking somehow:
    <div style={[styles.Header,{backgroundColor:this.state.themeColor}]}>
When only one style element or the other is present it works, but with both in the array, neither seem to function.  Any ideas?

Comment: Use `style={{backgroundColor: this.state.themeColor}}`

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes below to your code:

```
class General_header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // This will create a single object containing fields
    // from styles.header plus the extra backgroundColor field.
    const fullStyle = {
      ...styles.header, // This is called the spread operator
      backgroundColor: this.props.theme_color // No need to assign this to state
    }
    return (
      <div style={fullStyle}>test
        <img src={this.state.logo_img} alt={'logo'} style={styles.logo_img} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

ES5 version:

```
var fullStyle = Object.assign(
  {}, 
  styles.header, 
  { backgroundColor: this.props.theme_color }
);
```